# Only show moment date if AFTER today

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I am trying to get moment to only display a date if that date is AFTER today but I can't get it to work. Here's my code, any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<html>
<p class='round3due'></p>
</html>
<script>
var r3ChangesDue = moment().isoWeekday(5 + 7).format('M-DD-YY');


$(document).ready(function() {
   if (moment().isAfter(r3ChangesDue)){
    $( ".round3due" ).text(r3ChangesDue);
    }
    else{
    $( ".round3due" ).text('');
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"I can't get it to work"* What happens instead? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Nothing happens at all!

Comment: So, are you saying that the code doesn't even run?

Comment: Right, I can't get it to do anything and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If I take your code and change it so that it sets some text instead of an empty string, it clearly shows that it runs: http://jsfiddle.net/EE8rL/. So if it really doesn't run for you I assume you either haven't included jQuery or moment.js.

Comment: That's the weird thing, I have jQuery and moment.js all over that page...and those parts run. I can provide a link/HTML but it has to be privately, this is for a corp site